# How to use if to find a substring inside a string with JavaScript or jQuery, using TamperMonkey and possibly an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, match, tampermonkey

So I'm writing a Tampermonkey script for use on Facebook (as you might tell on the id's & classes) and I've run into a wall. Total writers block. I'm trying to figure out how I can write an if statement that will allow me to find specific strings in an existing string. Now, I've looked around for ideas and the regular expressions aren't working for me, nor is .test or .match working for me either. I'm a little confused and needing some insight as to what I might be able to do. I would love to use an array if possible since I'm going to be searching for so many strings.

Here is a snippet of the code where I need help:

```
var checkName = setInterval(function() {
    if ($("span[id^='fb-timeline-cover-name']").length) {
        var str = document.getElementById("fb-timeline-cover-name").innerText;
        var res = str.toLowerCase();
        if (res.substring(0,3) == "ssg") {
            $("button[id^='u_0_12']").click();
        }
        clearInterval(checkName);
    }
}, 50);
```

Instead of:

```
if(res.substring(0,3) == "ssg") {
```

I'd like to be able to do something simple like:

```
if(res.match(this_array)) {
```

But I'm sure that's the wrong syntax all together. Anyone? Help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: Well, the code as is works... but say I come across a string that says "asdf**ssg**asdf". It won't detect that. Not to mention that I also need to add more substrings to an array or something.

Answer (score 0):

It seems [String/match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) can be useful.

But I am not sure what is `this_array` referring here.

Hope this snippet will be useful

```
var str = document.getElementById("fb-timeline-cover-name").innerText;
var res = str.match(/asdfssgasdf/g);
document.write('<pre>'+res+'</pre>');
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qgr747rm/)

**EDIT**

Another String method that can be handy is [String includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

It retuns a boolean value, true or false

Comment: The "this_array" was just an idea for a possible array that hasn't been created yet. I'll need to search one string for several substrings. But for some reason, `str.match(/ssg/);` didn't work for me when I tried it.

Comment: I think you are missing /g flag

Comment: Entirely possible. It's late.

Answer (score 0):

Could try a [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) implementation as its cross browser compatible

```
    if (res.indexOf("ssg") !== -1) {
        $("button[id^='u_0_12']").click();
    }
```